# Firebase 5.0.0+ with iOS 7.0

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, ios7, compatibility

this is just a quick beginner question, but I would like to get the gist of how pod updates work:

in the update notes from Google it is explicitly said: "Firebase v5.0.0 removes support for iOS 7 and building with Xcode 7"

Does this mean that this Firebase version will simply not work on iOS 7? Or if I set deployment target 7.0 I will get errors in my code because it is no longer supported?

Or does it simply mean, that all will work as previously, aside from the newly added features?

Thanks a million.

Comment: What stops you from trying and learning yourself? I’m quite sure you’d get your answer faster that way. Anyhow - it most likely won’t compile.

Comment: I dont have access to my mac untill the evening, so I figured it would be faster to get an answer this way for the time being. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: @Losiowaty so if I want to make my app iOS 7+ compatible, I will have to download an older version of the Firebase SDK? And try not to update it?

Comment: Generally yes. Though they may block you from the server side. Why do you want to support iOS 7 though? According to https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/ 89% devices are using iOS 11/12. This leaves 11% for iOS 10, 9, 8 and lastly 7 combined.

Comment: Just out of curiosity really, wondering how backwards compatibility works if I encountered this scenario. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CocoaPods won't allow Firebase to be installed if the platform version is set less than 8.0 in the `Podfile`:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
```

Even if you do try to override options after installation, some Firebase feature support for iOS 7 was explicitly removed in Firebase 5. Also, there has been no testing of iOS 7 since Firebase 5 was released, so there may be additional undetected iOS 7 regressions.